# "Content" or "contents"

Tags: plural-forms

According to CPE Use of English, "content" and "contents" have different meanings. But which meanings are they talking about? The only singular form is given in #4.

> [content](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/content1?q=Content)
> 4 [singular]
> (following a noun)
> the amount of a substance that is contained in something else
> • food with a high fat content
> • water/moisture/protein/DNA content
> • the alcohol content of a drink
>
> (Oxford Learner's Dictionary)

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to tell us exactly what CPE Use of English says? What was the exact sentence or paragraph? Where does it say this? Please provide a link if possible. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips.

Answer (score 2):

From https://getproofed.com/writing-tips/word-choice-content-vs-contents/ :

> **Content** is an uncountable noun. We use it when referring to the contained thing as an undifferentiated whole (e.g., the “content of a speech”). **Contents** is a plural countable noun. We use it when the things in a container are separate and countable (e.g., book chapters in a “table of contents”).

So #4 in [the link provided in your question](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/content1?q=Content) would be an example of the uncountable noun (i.e. fat content).

An example of the usage for "contents" would be "*she went through the contents of her purse searching for her pen*".  The purse is the container and the items are the countable things.